# add text input on type enter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have this code that works for me, is that when I press on the enter, me replaces the text with a new one in the input, the question is how do to not Replace if it agrege

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl as model">
     <input type="text"  ng-model="c1ero" ng-cero="uno" >   
     <input type="text"  ng-model="model.eae" ng-cero="dos" >   
    </div> 

angular
.module("myApp",[])
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
 var model=this;
})
.directive ('ngCero', function($parse){
  var linkFunction =function(scope, element, attrs){
     element.bind("keypress", function(event) {
         if(event.which === 13) {  
           scope.$apply(function(){
            scope.$eval(attrs.ngCero, {'event': event});
             $parse(attrs.ngModel).assign(scope, '0, ');
             console.log(attrs);
           });
           event.preventDefault(); 
         }
     });
  };
  return{
    //controller: "myCtrl",
    link: linkFunction
  }
})
```

and the code pen: http://codepen.io/fernandooj/pen/EgmQmJ

Comment: What does it mean *the question is how do to not Replace if it agrege*?

Comment: hi @PankajParkar thanks for yor answer: if I'm typing any text, and pressed enter, I agrege, a new text,
now if I'm typing something, and pressed enter, me replaces the text

Comment: what should be expected behaviour then?

Comment: You already opened the same exact question and it was deleted because it wasn't clear.. Make yourself cleaer. Honestly use google translate with your language and it will be clearer.

Comment: @PankajParkar and as is done?